# How to block scp command for certain users and for outbound connections

Tags: ssh, scp

I can restrict certain users to prevent logging on to the system via SSH server by adding their usernames next to `DenyUsers` directive in `sshd_config` file.

Can I do the same for scp command?

**Edit:**

scp is blocked when I try to run scp on another machine or a user on the same machine. In that case, scp is blocked. However, scp works when I run the command in the restricted user's terminal. That is, SSH server does not block this outbound connection.

Is it possible to configure SSH server so that such outbound requests are also blocked?

Comment: scp runs over ssh. If that works for ssh, it works for scp too.

Comment: @mosvy, it didn't work for me. That is, scp is not being blocked while ssh is.

Comment: @mosvy, restricted user can use scp to transfer files when logged in.

Comment: You have mixed something up. Users listed in `DenyUsers` cannot use any of ssh, scp or sftp.

Comment: @mosvy, your point is valid when I try to run scp on another machine or a user on the same machine. In that case, scp is blocked. However, scp works when I run the command in the restricted user's terminal. That is, SSH server does not block this outbound connection.

Comment: How is that user "restricted" if he was able to log in in the first place? The ssh server does not care about outgoing connections. It just listens on an address/port for connections from remote users, and (if everything goes well and they clear all the hurdles) it serves them with a shell (or something more restricted, like sftp). If the user gets on a shell, it's not ssh's business to limit him in any way anymore.

Comment: @mosvy, I see. I need to restrict certain users to prevent them from transferring files. They can only use VNC to access their workspace (VNC clipboard has been disabled).

Comment: "_SSH server does not block this outbound connection_" - of course not. The server has no care of what your users are doing as clients.

Comment: You should edit the question in addition to writing comments. The question in its current form is quite unclear and readers should not have to read all the comments to understand what the question is really about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting you can use in the `sshd_config` file to control whether users can invoke the `ssh`, `scp`, `sftp` binaries (or any other binary) for outbound connections.

If you want to restrict users from invoking that binary, you must change the permissions so that they lack the execute permission on the binary.  For example, you could put all the users you want to access the binary into a single group, change the group of the `scp` binary to that group, and set the permissions on the binary to 0750.

In general, you will have a difficult time restricting outbound network access on a general-purpose Unix system because there are a huge number of ways someone can connect out.  You could try putting them into a restricted graphical session without access to a terminal (or the Run Application window) [like so](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en), but if a user has shell access, good luck.  You could also try a mandatory filtering proxy, but it's going to be hard to make that work securely with HTTPS connections.

Comment: That approach only makes sense if the users are forbidden from executing anything they have written to (mount at least `/home`, `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, `/dev/shm`, and `/run/user/*` (that's a fun one because a certain Lennart is nor smart enough and too arrogant to listen to others) with `noexec`).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to prevent the user from creating the binary on the system and run it (i.e. mount at least `/home`, `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, `/dev/shm`, and `/run/user/*` (that's a fun one because a certain Lennart is nor smart enough and too arrogant to listen to others) with noexec).

There might be an SSH daemon listening on a port other than 22. But if it is enough for you to prevent connections to that port then you may block connections to that port (for certain users) with Netfilter (`iptables`).

The question is whether blocking `scp` serves a useful purpose as there are so many ways to move data from or to a system...